# Test Driven Development

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have this code that I have written to check whether a string is all caps. If so, it returns True and if it's not all caps it returns False. I need to run unit tests for this solution but I am stuck.

If there a better or simpler code for the solution code? How can I unit test the solution? Is my attempt correct? if not could you please help me?

#### My solution code

```
def is_uppercase(x):
    words = x.split("_")
    for word in words:
        if word == word.upper():
            return True
        else:
            return False

is_uppercase("AM dONALD")
```

#### The attempted unit tests

```
import unittest
import Capss       #  solution code file name


class TestCaps(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_is_uppercase(self):
        self.assertTrue("FF", msg=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

When I run the solution code, passing the arguments with all caps or mix upper and lower cases, I get the expected True or False. However, when I manipulate the values in the unit tests, the result is just the same, nothing changes. Any help?

Comment: You are never using your `is_uppercase` function in the test script, so how do you expect it to be tested?

Comment: And what do you think `msg=True` means?

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
def test_is_uppercase(self):
    self.assertTrue("FF", msg=True)
```

There is only an assert in your test, but you are **not at all** invoking the actual "method under test" which you claim you want to test.

You have to invoke that method, and check for expected results, like:

```
self.assertTrue(is_uppercase("UPPER"))
self.assertFalse(is_uppercase("lower"))
self.assertFalse(is_uppercase("Mixed"))
```

The point of unit tests is to call your "production code" functions, and to check if they deliver the expected result.

There is no magic here, the unittest environment can't **guess** that you imported `Capps` because you magically want to have your `is_uppercase()` tested!